# reset jquery max-height when device orientation changes

Tags: jquery, html, css, reset

I am using this read more function
https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

When the viewing on a mobile/tablet device and you click the read more button then change the orientation of your device the height of the box is either too large (going from portrait to landscape) or getting cut off (going from landscape to portrait).

Is there a way in the jQuery to reset this height when the orientation changes?
This is the code I am using

```
<script>
var jq14 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // your logic

        var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)");

        var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

        $(".fade-box .button-read-on").click(function () {

            totalHeight = 0

            $el = $(this);
            $p = $el.parent();
            $up = $p.parent();
            $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

            // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
            $ps.each(function () {
                totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
                // FAIL totalHeight += $(this).css("margin-bottom");
            });

            $up
                .css({
                    // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
                    "height": $up.height(),
                    "max-height": 9999
                })
                .animate({
                    "height": totalHeight
                })
                .click(function () {
                    //After expanding, click paragraph to revert to original state
                    $p.fadeIn();

                    if (mq.matches) {
                        $up.animate({
                            "height": 190
                        });
                    } else {
                        $up.animate({
                            "height": 210
                        });
                    }

                });

           // fade out read-more
           $p.fadeOut();

           // prevent jump-down
           return false;

       });
   });
```

}(jq14));

Answer (score 1):

You can use **orientation change** from jQuery Mobile

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
  //you can get the screen size
  var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  //some code
});
```

Note that you will need jQuery Mobile for this, Im not sure if it works with regular jQuery but it is worth giving a look

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. jQuery is not my forte, would you be able to let me know where this would fit in my code?

Comment: Sure, but first I would need to understand what you're trying to do... Is it to adjust the element's height and width to match with those of the device?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have decided to go with another option.

Answer (score 0):

am try this.its work for me. enjoy =)

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
   // Announce the new orientation number
   //alert(screen.orientation);
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   alert("width = " + windowWidth+"  " +" height = "+ windowHeight);
 
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not quite what I am after. I need the totalHeight to reload.